# Is the annexation of a vassal giving you the control of its colonial nations?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I vassalized Portugal. Ten years after, I can annex it. I must choose to wait or not for Portugal to make some colonies before to annex it. In case I will gain its dependencies later, I will wait. Else I would annex it now.

**Is the annexation of a vassal giving you the control of its colonial nations? Do you gain all its dependencies?**

Comment: I forgot to say that I would like to wait because I don't have technologies to colonize over-sea but my vassal can.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think that yes. As when you enter into a PU, you receive all the vassals of the PU.

Comment: Mention from user Gags (who can't post comments due to low rep): "I played as Ethiopia and force vassalized a country that was in a PU. When I annexed, the lesser partner then became my vassal. Sample size of one, but that was my experience."

Comment: In one of my recent game, playing as Portugal, I was the major partner in a union with Castille. Eventually, I inherited the throne and also all the colonies.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will gain all colonies.

They will however keep their name and color IIRC.